# Java Google Calendar parse events

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, java-7, google-api-java-client

I'm not able to parse the Google Calendar events with the Google Calendar API.

```
URL feedUrl = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/"+ emailAddress +"/events/");
EventFeed eventFeed = calendarService.getFeed(feedUrl, EventFeed.class);
```

Exception, last line:

```
com.google.gdata.util.ParseException: Unrecognized content type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: you might want to start with using the V3 version of the API instead of the gdata version.    https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gdata.util` leads me to believe that you are trying to use the Gdata client library.

But you appear to be trying to feed it the end point for V3 of the Google Calendar API.  Which isn't going to work because the V3 of the Google Calendar is a discovery service API and not a GData API.   Discovery API return jSon, gData APIs return xml so there is no way the gData Client library can understand what the V3 API is trying to tell it.  Hence the `Unrecognized content type:application/json`

I think you should start by downloading the current [Google API java client library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/).

Also note that the GData version of the [Google Calendar API was shut down November 17, 2014](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.dk/2014/10/deprecated-google-calendar-apis-v1-v2.html)   So I don't believe you will be able to use the gdata client library to access Google Calendar

Comment: Thanks, I thought it's the same as google contacts. Is there a possibility to set the accessToken to get the events? https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get#examples

Comment: That's a different question and one I can't help with.   I have very little experience with the Java client lib.   Try making a new question someone will probably be able to answer.   Google contacts is a gdata api that's why it works.

Comment: Thanks, I think I've found a solution:GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(accessToken);
        Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName("App-Name").build();